# After creating shipment plan through MWS feed, not sure how to create shipment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am a little stuck and confused on something.  I read through the following API which details how to create an FBA inbound shipment "plan" by using [Amazon's MWS feed API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_IT/feeds/Feeds_FeedType.html)

[I used the following template from Amazon to create the shipment plan flat file](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/rainier/help/ff/in/Flat.File.CreateInboundPlanRequest._V340671273_.xls)

Great.  I successfully implemented the API and used `_POST_FLAT_FILE_FBA_CREATE_INBOUND_PLAN_`  to submit the flat file to MWS for processing.  All works well, and I see my new shipment plan in the plan's list, and it returns me back a Plan ID.

I just don't know what to do next.  I want to now create a shipment from that plan, with all of the items in it (no modifications).  The document suggests I use `_POST_FLAT_FILE_FBA_CREATE_INBOUND_SHIPMENT_`, but I can't find any details on what template to use for it, or how I even specify the Plan ID that was returned to me from creating the inbound plan.

Can anyone provide some guidance on the "next step" for creating the actual inbound shipment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Amazon MWS for FBA Sellers](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/fba/MWSForFBASellers._V344220563_.pdf) guide recommends using the [CreateInboundShipmentPlan](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inbound/FBAInbound_CreateInboundShipmentPlan.html) and [CreateInboundShipment](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inbound/FBAInbound_CreateInboundShipment.html) API calls, neither of which needs a flat file. From past experience I strongly recommend not using CSV files if you can avoid it: there are many pitfalls. But if you must, here are XLS files describing both [CreateInboundShipmentRequest](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/ff/Flat.File.CreateInboundShipmentRequest.xls) and [UpdateInboundShipmentRequest](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/ff/Flat.File.UpdateInboundShipmentRequest.xls).

Comment: where did you find those XLS files?  I couldn't seem to find them in their documentation.

Comment: @gnychis : Unfortunately, the "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help" directory (which is where your template came from) is not browsable, but Google came to the rescue: searching for "Flat File CreateInboundShipmentRequest xls" gives pretty good results including links to other files in that directory. I still have no idea why a lot of MWS documentatin lies in that location, or who the heck this Rainier guy is, but I assume he is someone on the MWS development team.